# Angular4 & Karma - Custom Test Location outside of src folder

Tags: angular, karma-runner

Is there a way to point Karma to look for tests in a folder outside of the src folder in an Angular 4 app? The team I am working with has created a library/ folder that is a sibling to src/ and asked me to put my work in there, including my .spec.ts files. Below is a simplification of the file structure. I want to point karma to the library/ folder. Right now, it is only looking at the src/ folder. Is this possible?

`MyApp/
|
|--src/
|   |
|   |--app/
|   |--test.ts
|
|--library/
|   |--my-component-1/
|       |
|       |--my-component-1.component.ts
|       |--my-component-1.component.spec.ts
|
|--karma.conf.js`